# PHP Return not working in Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

I tried running the following code and it supposed to pick the value from the database but not picking.

```
            $val = doautocomp('Brisbane');

        HTTP::redirect($url_address.'/hotel-search/go/' . $val);
        exit;
    }
    else {
        HTTP::redirect($url_address.'/hotel-search/error');
        exit;
    }
}
function seoUrl($string) {
        $string = strtolower($string);
        $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $string);
        $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);
        $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $string);
        return $string;
}
function doautocomp($mval) {
    $linker = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass');
    $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM the.autocompletes where name LIKE '".$mval."%' LIMIT 0,1");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
      {
          $val1 = $row['name'];
          $mval = seoUrl($val1);

      }
      return $mval;
      mysql_close($linker);
}
```

I also tried as but still its not working. **RETURN TEST**

```
        $val = doautocomp('Brisbane');

        HTTP::redirect($url_address.'/hotel-search/go/' . $val);
        exit;
    }
    else {
        HTTP::redirect($url_address.'/hotel-search/error');
        exit;
    }
}
function seoUrl($string) {
        $string = strtolower($string);
        $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $string);
        $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);
        $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $string);
        return $string;
}
function doautocomp($mval) {
    $linker = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass');
    $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM the.autocompletes where name LIKE '".$mval."%' LIMIT 0,1");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
      {
          $val1 = $row['name'];
          $mval = seoUrl($val1);

      }
      return "test"; //$mval;
      mysql_close($linker);
}
```

Comment: This code looks structural. What's the context of this code? A plain script, or a controller? You don't seem to be using Kohana here at all (except the HTTP class which is irrelevant).

Comment: Just a thing. Try not to use the old mysql extension and use either the query builder or ORM from Kohana or the newer mysqli extension. Also about the question, please post the whole code or give some more information regarding your problem.

Comment: @Manuras Kohana actually uses the mysql_ stuff (or PDO), 3.4 will bring us MySQLi though. (You are perfectly right though)

Comment: Something makes me think you are mixing Kohana versions 2.x and 3.x syntax. They are very different beasts.

Answer (score 2):

I have some problems understanding your code right. You are using a framework with a good database class. Why do you use "mysql_connect". Your "mysql_close()" comes under the "return" statement. So maybe your last connection isn't closed right. Did you try a return "TEST" before mysql is used?

You should write your code more like this:

```
function doautocomp($mval) {

    $row = Database::instance()->query(Database::SELECT,
        DB::select('name')
            ->from('autocompletes')
            ->where('name','LIKE',$mval.'%')
            ->limit(1)
        )->current();

    if ($row === FALSE)
    {
        return "";
    }

    $val1 = $row['name'];
    $mval = seoUrl($val1);

    return $mval;
}
```